# How to change the color of the text or the divider color of the date picker in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog

I have been trying to update the textcolor and the divider color of the DatePicker but in vain.

My Datepicker inside the Fragment -

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/datePickerContainer"
        style="@style/wertyui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:spinnersShown="true" />
```

The style of datepicker-

```
<style name="wertyui" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light">

        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
        <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
        <item name="android:spinnersShown">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/colorAccent</item>


    </style>
```

The Style of the Activity -

```
<style name="themex" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#cccccc</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@color/white_pressed</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#212121</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#212121</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.03</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#CCCCCC</item>

    </style>
```

I have tried every way but the colors are not changing.

As you can see, i am using @android:style/Widget.Holo.Light theme.

On Lollipop, the divide color is default blue but on Android pie or oreo it is BLack. How to change the Color.

I don't want to use any library. Is there any direct way to do this using XML or programmatically?